# Build a reusable Vue component based on an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, dhtmlx

I'm trying to build a reusable component of Vue based of a DHTMLX Grid, the component is inicialized from an object but the problem Is that I'm trying to build a generic component with the intention of using it multiple times in a single page and inside of that component I have an object declaration named grid which Is the object that I use for creating the grid.

The declaration looks like that:

```
this.grid = new GridDHX(idGrid, {
        columns: X,
        height: X,
        selection: "simple",
        data: X,
      });
```

But when I inicialize the component multiple times because the object name Is the same In every inicialitzation I encounter these errors:

```
Method "grid" has type "object" in the component definition. Did you reference the function correctly?

Method "grid" has already been defined as a data property.
```

Basically the problem Is that the name of the object inside the component Is reused multiple times so It's like It can't detect which component Is which.

How can I create a reusable Vue component without these problem?

Comment: Can you show us the component? We can't help much without additional data here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each of your grid objects should have a unique name, otherwise you need to destroy a current grid object with the destructor() method
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/suite/grid__api__grid_destructor_method.html
before creating a new one with the same name

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can check the example of DHX Grid wrapper for Vue

https://github.com/DHTMLX/vue-suite-demo/blob/master/src/components/grid/GridBase.vue

and live demo here

https://dhtmlx.github.io/vue-suite-demo/?path=/story/grid--base

```js
import { Grid as GridDHX } from "dhx-suite";
export default {
  name: "GridBase",
  data: () => ({
    grid: null,
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.grid = new GridDHX(this.$refs.grid, {
```